# Nuxt.js i18n default language 'Page not found'

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am having a problem with my Nuxt.js app.

I have installed nuxt-i18n 5.8.0, and made the following configuration in my nuxt.config.js file

```
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    locales: [
      {
        name: 'English',
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      },
      {
        name: 'Greek',
        code: 'el',
        iso: 'el-GR',
        file: 'el-GR.js'
      }
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: process.env.DEFAULT_LANG || 'en',
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
    seo: false
  }
]
```

When I am in the default language, and clicking on a link in the page, the result is a 'Page not found' error. If I refresh the page, it works.

This happens in every page for every link with the default language.

If I use the secondary language, navigation works fine.

Any help??

Thnx!!

Answer (score 0):

**i was has same issue to fix it add disable the detect browser language in** :

```
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    ...
    detectBrowserLanguage: false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set fallbackLocale like below:

```
// nuxt.config.js

{
  modules: [
    [
      'nuxt-i18n',
      {
        locales: ['en', 'es'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        vueI18n: {
          fallbackLocale: 'en',
          messages: {
            en: {
              greeting: 'Hello world!'
            },
            es: {
              greeting: '¡Hola mundo!'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Please read link below for more information:

https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module

Answer (score 0):

add this line to i18n in your nuxt.config.js

strategy: 'prefix_and_default'